# Why do I have a white box at the bottom of my page and how do I fix it?

Tags: html, css

I have random white spaces at the bottom of my website. I am a new developer and I dont understand CSS that much yet.

My site: https://sirleo.tk

Comment: Unclear what you r problem is. Your content does not fill up the whole page so the color you see is the background of the document. `html { background-color: #DFDFDF; }`

Comment: you could give your body a min height of 100vh. You could make your body position absolute and inset 0 to take up all the space. You could just remove the background color on your html element.

Comment: Please create a reproducible snippet inside the question.

Comment: where is the white box...? your body is taking only 40% max height of the screen. 
 https://imgur.com/a/YBmJU6n

Comment: Code you add some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<div class="colour"></div>` needs a height 100vh in order to take all the screen view height;

```css
.colour{
height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: I am trying this on my other pages, but it is cutting off the main page. Any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Because the body element's height is set according to your elements inside it.

If You want to make it full screen set a specific height to your body element like body{height: 100vh;}

Or You can just set your HTML background color like html { background-color: #1b1c1c; }